# Is there a way to improve this sql select function?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to use SELECT statement in mysql to find a set of employee datas from "Asia" However there is no primary key or foreign key in the EMPLOYEE data. So I used department name as it has the link towards country names

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, job_title, email 
FROM EMPLOYEE

WHERE department_name IN ( 
SELECT department_name
FROM DEPARTMENT
WHERE country_name = 'China' 
      OR country_name = 'India' 
      OR country_name = 'Japan' 
      OR country_name = 'Singapore'
);

SELECT country_name FROM COUNTRY 
WHERE region_name = 'Asia'
```

Comment: I'm wondering if there is any way to include my SELECT COUNTRY statement inside the nested query?

Comment: Does department table has `country_name` as primary key? Also is department_name in primary key for Employee table? Why do you want improvement? Is it taking long or its just the query format you dont like?

Comment: I don't see any reason for the inner SELECT. Just use its WHERE clause in the outer select. I als don't see the point of the final SELECT.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your comment:

> I'm wondering if there is any way to include my SELECT COUNTRY
>   statement inside the nested query?

Use IN like this:

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, job_title, email 
FROM EMPLOYEE
WHERE department_name IN ( 
  SELECT department_name
  FROM DEPARTMENT
  WHERE country_name IN (
    SELECT country_name FROM COUNTRY 
    WHERE region_name = 'Asia'
  )
);
```

Answer (score 0):

An other way (not necessarily an improvement) is:

```
SELECT employee_id, first_name, last_name, job_title, email 
FROM EMPLOYEE e
INNER JOIN DEPARTMENT d ON department_name = e.department_name
INNER JOIN COUNTRY c ON c.country_name = d.country_name
WHERE c.region_name = 'Asia'
```